# Access Tags inside a HTML table through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have following table structure:

```
<table id="currentloc_table">
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Details</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id='viewonMapCheckbox' type='checkbox'></td>
        <td>
            <span class="tooltip" href="#">
                <span class="custom info">
                    <em>
                    </em>
                    Last Activity: 2013-03-12 03:29:21<br/>
                    Latitude: <span id="lat">30</span><br/>
                    Longitude: <span id="lon">70</span><br/>
                </span>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>Details</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to set Latitude and Longitude values using Javascript but not able to make it work. Please help me out. Here is the code which i have written:

```
var loc_table = document.getElementById('currentloc_table');
var loc_table_rows_count = document.getElementById('currentloc_table').getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
for (var i = 0; i < loc_table_rows_count; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {//skipping header row
        var row = loc_table.rows[i];
        row.cells[1].firstChild.firstChild.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = "31";
        row.cells[1].firstChild.firstChild.getElementById("lon").innerHTML = "71";
   }
}
```

Comment: why are you using loop if you have single row?

Comment: @cris there can be multiple rows. I showed single row as sample data.

Comment: then each lat and lon will have same id,make sure you have diffrent ids or access them by name

Answer (score 2):

`id` is a global field, just do this:

```
document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = "31";
document.getElementById("lon").innerHTML = "71";
```

instead of what you have written.

Comment: When do you call the javascript code? You can't just assign these values at the very start, you should run this javascript code only when page is fully loaded. Look at body `onload` event to be able to run something when your page is loaded: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp

Comment: actually i am already doing exactly what you advised. This code is written in JS function which is fired on pageload.

Comment: In that case you should be having something other on your html page, because I just copy-pasted this and when executing JS it changed values.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to have more than one row. In this case you can't use ID's for spans (we should have one unique ID on page).
About resolving your task:
Change your `ID` attribute to `CLASS`.
Simple JS solution:

```
var loc_table = document.getElementById('currentloc_table');
var loc_table_rows = loc_table.getElementsByClassName("table_row");
for (var i = 0; i < loc_table_rows.length; i++) {
    var row = loc_table_rows[i];
    var rowLatitude=row.getElementsByClassName('lat')[0].innerHTML='31';
    var rowLongitude=row.getElementsByClassName('lon')[0].innerHTML='71';
}
```

HTML example:

```
<table id="currentloc_table">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Details</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table_row">
        <td>
            Latitude: <span class="lat">30</span><br/>
            Longitude: <span class="lon">70</span><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table_row">
        <td>
            Latitude: <span class="lat">30</span><br/>
            Longitude: <span class="lon">70</span><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you please suggest Javascript code to achieve this instead through jquery. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var loc_table = document.getElementById('currentloc_table');
var loc_table_rows_count = document.getElementById('currentloc_table').getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
for (var i = 1; i < loc_table_rows_count; i++) {
        document.getElementById("lat"+i).innerHTML = "31";
        document.getElementById("lon"+i).innerHTML = "71";
}
```

And in your HTML, add the number of the row in the `id` attribute.
For example :

```
<table id="currentloc_table">
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Details</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id='viewonMapCheckbox' type='checkbox'></td>
        <td>
            <span class="tooltip" href="#">
                <span class="custom info">
                    <em>
                    </em>
                    Last Activity: 2013-03-12 03:29:21<br/>
                    Latitude: <span id="lat1">30</span><br/>
                    Longitude: <span id="lon1">70</span><br/>
                </span>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>Details</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What append? Give more explanation... Do you add an row index in the ID of span, to make sure that **all id** are **unique**